# Ordering in #include directive

Tags: c++, c

I understand the difference between

```
#include "xyz"
```

and

```
#include <xyz>
```

in terms of what location is searched in each case.

I would like to know whether there is an ordering according to which searching and linking is done. Are files using

```
#include "xyz" //as this is done in current working directory
```

linked before linking of files using

```
#include <xyz>
```

Comment: This is not "linking".

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor includes have nothing to do with linking. This is a common misconception.

There is no assumption anywhere that one include corresponds to something being linked. Notice that the standard library has lots of headers, but generally only consists of a single library when the linking happens.

With e.g. gcc (and most other compilers) you can compile a C file first, then compile a bunch of other C files, then finally do the linking of all the object files with any required external libraries. When you do the linking, you're operating on *already-compiled* files (object files and libraries); these files know nothing about the order in which the preprocessor directives appeared in the original source, that is long gone.

Comment: I think it's clear he simply misused the term. The question isn't actually about linking.

Comment: I doubt that this is a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

`#include "file"` will search in current directory before searching in include path. There is no mechanism  to specify the order of linking of object files.

Answer (score 1):

`#include file` directive tells the preprocessor to treat the contents of a specified `file` as if it appears in the source program at the point where the directive appears.

It is not related to linking.